# WCF service inaccessible after logging in

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, asp.net-ajax, impersonation

I'm having a WCF issue when deploying to our pre-production environment.  It is working fine locally. 
The AJAX message I'm getting is that there has been a parse error, but I am unable to get any trace logging going on the preprod server, but again, logging is working fine on my local (with same webconfig settings).
The only time the Traces.svlog will record anything on preprod is when the app domain is unloaded.  On my local, I can throw deliberate exceptions and this will get picked up in the log.

If I am logged in, I am unable to navigate to path of the service, instead an  exception is thrown (see below).  However, if I don't login, I can access the service page and click into the wsdl, and see the methods etc.  I have know idea what is going wrong after login.

Exception:

```
Process information: 
Process ID: 4796 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
Exception type: InvalidCastException 
Exception message: Unable to cast object of type
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler' to type 'System.Web.UI.Page'. 

Request information: 
Request URL: http://100.100.100.104/Application/Webservices/People.svc/GetAllActive
Request path: /Application/Webservices/People.svc/GetAllActive
User host address: 102.24.1.152 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: domainA\userB

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 7 
Thread account name: domainA\userB
Is impersonating: True 
Stack trace:    at ASP.global_asax.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute
                (Object sender, EventArgs e)
at
System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

We are running IIS6  on the preprod environment.

At first, I noticed that the svc extension was not there in IISManager -> AppplicationProperies->HomeDirectory->Configuration.  I then added it manually.

Following this, and due to what I had read elsewhere, I also ran the following two commands from the correct locations:

```
aspnet_regiis -i

ServiceModelReg.exe -i
```

Again, they did nothing to fix the error.

My main confusion is that I can type into URL and access the svc wsdl as long as I'm not logged in.  As you can see from error message above, our webconfig is using impersonate - not sure if this has any effect.

My service directory struct is such

```
Application
->AppCode
...->People.vb
->DirA
...->DirB
......->Calling.aspx
->WebServices
...->People.svc
```

My ajax call in Calling.aspx looks like the following:

```
jQuery_1_8_3(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery_1_8_3.ajaxSetup({
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        converters: {
            "json jsond": function(msg) {
                return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
            }
        }

    });


    jQuery_1_8_3.ajax({
    url: "../../Webservices/People.svc/GetAllActive",
        success: function(resdata) {

            //etc
        }
    });
```

The svc looks like the following:

And My Vb looks like the following:

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="people")> _
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
Public Class People

<CLSCompliant(False)> _
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,  RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
 Public Function GetAllActive() As PersonDetailDataContract()
   Dim service As New RepositoryService()
   Dim personList As IList(Of Interfaces.ModelInterfaces.IPersonDetail)
    personList = service.GetAllPersonDetails()

    Dim contractList As New ArrayList()

    For Each
     //Populate contractlist, etc
    Next

    Dim array() As PersonDetailDataContract
    array = contractList.Cast(Of PersonDetailDataContract)().ToArray()

    Return array

End Function

End Class
```

As you can see, I haven't bothered to create a separate interface for the contract - I've just put it on the concrete class.

(I've also anonymised the code and ip's, etc).

My Webconfig looks as follows (minus the massive multitude of others things for other apps in there.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"  />

    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traceListener"
                    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                    initializeData= "C:\svclogs\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
   </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
          logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
          logMalformedMessages="true"
          logEntireMessage="true"
          maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000" maxMessagesToLog="500" />
  </diagnostics>
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="PeopleTypeBehaviors" >
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="json">
              <webHttp/>

          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
      <service name="People" behaviorConfiguration="PeopleTypeBehaviors">

          <endpoint address="" 
                    behaviorConfiguration="json"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" 
                    contract="People" />
          <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" 
                    binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                    address="mex" />
      </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
```

I'm becoming kind of stumped here, and I'm very new to WebServices of any kind.  However, I hope I've provided enough information so that others can perhaps see the issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was that there was an issue in the global_asax.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute (clue was in the flipping exception - doh!)

The procedure was attempting to cast the handler to a page, which it obviously wasn't as was an ajax request.  I just put a trycast on the cast handler call instead and the rest of procedure was bypassed allowing request to return with result.